Right implementation Unit of Work pattern
I want to implement Unit of Work for my ecommerce shop project, but I don't understand and can't find how to make it so repositories are gonna be generic and anytime I want to create new model my generic repository don't violate Interface segregation principle. If, for example, I create new model, and I don`t need Update implementation it will be added anyway. I know that I can make all my repo calls in services and then only save changes in UnitOfWork, also if I will not create generic repo, I will be violating open closed principle. Here generic repo
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
    }
    public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
    }
    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Update(entity);
    }
    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}

Here Unit Of Work:
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (_repositories.ContainsKey(typeof(TEntity)))
            return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[typeof(TEntity)];

        var repository = new Repository<TEntity>(_context);
        _repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);
        return repository;
    }
    public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}


Create Generic repositories for each method, in this way you may inherit only required methods. So if you don't require Update method at all, just don't inherit that interface.

You're just creating a wrapper around the EF context. EF already is a UOW. If you want flexibility with your gets, just return an IQueryable<>.

Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore is abstraction over databases and DbContext is already UoW and DbSet is already Repository. Why do you need another abstraction?

I'm studying right now so I`m not sure, I just saw a lot of guides use it. So you recommend not to use unit of work and interact with my database, for example, in services? I saw that UoW helps to make all transactions before saving and can help to stop process if somewhere is error, without it you can save some changes before the error part start to execute.

DbContext implements UoW, before SaveChanges modifications are collected in  DbContext's ChangeTracker. Anyway nice reading Is Repository an anti-pattern?

Do not use a Generic Repository over-top of EF. It is an anti-pattern, and holds a top position amongst the worst things you can do with EF. EF already provides a generic repository in the form of the DbSet<TEntity> and the DbContext already serves as the Unit of Work. EF's power is in its ability to leverage IQueryable to facilitate projection and work with aggregate root entity structures through navigation properties.
Already your implementation only offers asynchronous methods for reading data, what happens if you need synchronous? async isn't a magic "go faster" keyword. It is actually slightly slower. It offers an advantage when operations might otherwise block something like ASP.Net Controllers which could be responding to other requests rather than waiting on a long query, but if you want to fetch something simple, fast, synchronous has a smaller footprint.
Methods like:
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
}

... you will NEVER want to see that method called in production code. How does a consumer sort the results? How do they filter the results? What if they only need a count? What if they only need a handful of fields from the entity? What if they want the entity, but you also want some of the related data as well? (Eager loading) This method fetches all rows every time into memory. 10M rows? all in memory. Want them sorted or filtered? sorted & filtered after-the fact in memory rather than letting the database, which is optimized for this, do it.  Sure, you could pass parameters, stacks and stacks of optional parameters for sorting, filtering, pagination, etc, and complex parameters like Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> filters or IEnumerable<(string, bool)> sortBy which is complex and half-assed, all to try and abstract EF-isms from your consuming code. Except it doesn't. The expressions still need to conform to EF rules to get translated down into SQL. They cannot call C# functions or use unmapped columns, etc.
It's good that you are aware of SOLID and other principles of software design. When it comes to software patterns and principles, the ranking of importance on decisions would be something like:
KISS (Keep It Stupid Simple) > SOLID (Single Responsibility > Dependency Inversion > Liskov Substitution > Interface Segregation > Open Closed) >>> DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
My hunch when I see efforts to treat principles and such as gospel is that something like DRY gets put on the pedestal as the most important goal where SOLID's purpose is ultimately to satisfy DRY. DRY is an excellent consideration for re-factoring, not software design. Design and implement for the simplest thing first with considerations for SOLID principles. As you have capability laid out, working, and proven THEN re-factor, tweak, & tighten. Reversing the order and thinking too hard about what "perfect" code should look like results in premature optimization and more often than not leads to worse solutions that are more rigid, harder to understand, less performant and fail at the most important goal of software, satisfying user expectations and requirements. (Accuracy, performance, and cost)
